# On-Premise and on-demand Lab VM

Tags: automation, virtual-machine, templating

**Problem** - I am consolidating the management of my company's short-life-Windows-VM needs. I would like to templatize servers loaded up with versions of our software, which could then be repeatedly (and automatically?) deployed for multiple use cases, like sales demos, implementation, and support.

**Requirements** - Ideally, the creation of a VM could be triggered when a request of some kind is submitted through an internal portal. We absolutely need these VMs to be available to mobile apps via the internet. Additionally, our software requires Active Directory and Microsoft SQL Server DBMS.

**Research** - We have looked into some cloud solutions like Ravello and Cloudshare, but our need for mobile access on the internet is a limiting factor. I am also planning on looking into OpenStack, but have been unable so far to determine if OpenStack has this capability, or of there is a supplementary software that might add this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this. If anyone else is looking for such a product, give [CloudShell](http://www.quali.com/cloudshell-platform/) a look.